# OCaml: How to traverse a list parameter in a record type

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, record

If I have a data structure such as

```
type cost = int

type 'a map = {
  cities : 'a list
  routes : ('a * 'a * cost) list
}
```

And say I have a function with a header such as

```
let nearest_cities (m : 'a map) = ...
```

and I want to recursively traverse the routes list, what would be the best and cleanest way of going about this? I tried to match on the record, however I'm not sure how to recursively update the parameters of the record

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want to update the record, but the record type as you have defined it is immutable. You can't change the values of the fields of such a record. The usual way to handle this in a functional language is to create a new record with the desired new contents.

You say you want to "traverse" the list, but this isn't specific enough to offer a detailed suggestion. There are functions in the `List` module for various kinds of traversal: `List.iter`, `List.map`, `List.fold_left`, and so on.

As an example, here is a function that increments all the costs of a value of type `'a map`:

```
 let cost_incr map =
      { map with routes =
            List.map (fun (a, b, c) -> (a, b, c + 1)) map.routes
      }
```

(Also note you need `;` after the definition of the `cities` field in the record type.)